# Best practices for storing data in iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, core-data

I am creating iOS app where user authenticates through facebook and allows my app to store some data like (name,email,gender,location) . I want to use this data later in my app for specific purpose.

- What are the best practices of storing/retrieving this kind of data?
- I have read about CoreData and NSCoding. Are those the best
  alternatives if there will be huge data in future?
- Should i retrieve    this data from facebook everytime user accesses
  the app instead of    storing in my app?

Comment: If you just store simple datas such as names, emails, etc, `NSUserDefaults` is probably the easiest way.

Comment: Sure..i am looking at a big picture where I have thousands of users

Answer (score 0):

I think CoreData is the best way to go.

[developer.apple.com/CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)